Login problem after Update to 24.04
I've updated my system from 22.04 to 24.04 and now I get a screen telling me to logout the user. If I press this it seems to reboot quickly and then reappear again. So it's like in an endless loop.
In the background I do receive calendar information, so I assume that my system should still be intact in the background except for the login or logout process.
I have no idea what to do, I think I can start the system with CLI but don't know what to change or do there.
Maybe someone can help me out, this would be very nice.




I tried this solutioins, but it did not help.
https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop-ubuntu/

I also followed this instructions, but nothing helped
https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-ubuntu-login-loop-issue/

There is something wrong with your gnome configuration or your problem is related to some gnome bugs in 24.04. I suggest you press Ctrl+Alt+F5 and login with your user. Then fully update your system with sudo apt update and sudo apt dist-upgrade. If that doesn't solve your problem, please create a new system user and try to login to Gnome with that user. If that works, you may have to reset some gnome configurations (like themes) in your old user.

Thanks for your answere. I did that but no sucess.. I created also a new user and with cli I am able to login also with my main account. So this is not the problem I asume.
Could the problem be a graphical issue?
Or is there any possibility so see the problem, I mean with logs or so?

It's still not working. I can use the mouse to remove calender popups but the screen still the same. I can't loggout, if I press the button to loggout user it gets quickly black and come back here.

While doing this, sudo apt update and sudo apt dist-upgrade, I get quite a lote of errors. It seams that that updating is not finishing propperly.
3 updates are available but not installing.
gnome-remote-desktop
gnome-text-editor
ubuntu-settings
See second image in my post

I manualy updated this three packages and unfortunaly stil get this screen when booting up.
sudo apt update and sudo apt dist-upgrade all packages are updated and recent.
I have no clue what to do now

So still trying to fiund out what is wrong. By login in with my test account and then rebooting in cli I get the message that the main user is logged in on tty2. So I tried to kill all with $ sudo pkill -9 -u user and sudo pkill -9 -s PID and also sudo killall -u user but nothing works. still get the message that the main user is logged in on tty2....any ideas?
See the third screenshot
